# JQM navbar last button not align

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

This is a peculiar thing. The last button is always mis-aligned vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/5u38gf00/

```
<div data-role="navbar">    
<ul>      
    <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">one</a>
    </li>      
    <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a>
    </li>      
    <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">three</a>
    </li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

The code is straight forward from the jqm website. I've checked the css properties and it looks fine.

Comment: Try this:- http://jsfiddle.net/5u38gf00/1/. is that working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just try this http://jsfiddle.net/5u38gf00/1/

I just change the `onLoad` event to `onDomReady` event, then it seems work fine

**[EDIT]**
This will be the simple test code to display desired output in .html page. (Tested local)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**OutPut:-**  [image]

Comment: Thanks that works but how do I get it to work on a regular html page? I include the standard cdn <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you show me your html page code where you add the script reference?

Comment: Thanks. There were some invisible characters in the html that caused the mis-align! Don't ask me how. I'm using Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1):

I am using notepad++, and picked up that the spaces were actual spaces within the document - that I used to indent the tags. I changed over to tabs and that sorted the misalignment of the last button.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (some extra "invisibles" caracters). I have done a copy/paste from the official jquery mobile demo sample, so i think it's a "bug"in this doc ... 
I've just removed the white space before the UL and LI tags, and now it works fine